# Repeatedly Download File on background Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-backup-service

This is my code. When i click download button, it download twice. How to stop second time downloading? Please help me to prevent second time downloading.
this my button click listener:

```
 downloadPackage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        downloadPackage.setEnabled(false);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SETID", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putInt("setId", setId);
                        editor.commit();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ReadingListeningTestActivity.this, DownloadService.class);
                        startService(intent);
                    }
                });
```

this is my
Download Service:

```
public class DownloadService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
    private int totalFileSize;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    private boolean isDownloading = false;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("SETID", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int setId = prefs.getInt("setId", 0);
        Log.d("SEtID", setId + "");
        if (isDownloading) {
            return;
        } else {
            Log.d("Download", "isDownloading: " + isDownloading);
            isDownloading = true;
            initDownload(setId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void initDownload(int setId) {
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .setContentTitle(data.getTitle())
                                .setContentText("Downloading File")
                                .setAutoCancel(true);
                        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
                        downloadFileTest("test.zip");
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();

    }

    private void downloadFileTest(String uri) {
        int count;
        InputStream stream = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String fileName = packageName(uri);

        try {
            URL url = new URL(Application.BASE_URL + uri);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return;
            }
            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long fileSize = connection.getContentLength();
            stream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            File outputFile = getCacheDir(fileName + ".part");
            output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            try {
                long total = 0;
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int timeCount = 1;
                while ((count = stream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    totalFileSize = (int) (fileSize / (Math.pow(1024, 2)));
                    double current = Math.round(total / (Math.pow(1021, 2)));
                    int progress = (int) ((total * 100) / fileSize);
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    Download download = new Download();
                    download.setTotalFileSize(totalFileSize);
                    if (currentTime > 1000 * timeCount) {
                        download.setCurrentFileSize((int) current);
                        download.setProgress(progress);
                        sendNotification(download);
                        timeCount++;
                    }
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                isDownloading = false;
                prefs.edit().clear().commit();
                outputFile.delete();
                onErrorDownload("Internet Connection Problem Retry Download");
            } finally {
                isDownloading = false;
                prefs.edit().clear().commit();
                File originalName = getCacheDir(fileName);
                if (originalName.exists()) {
                    outputFile.delete();
                    throw new IOException("file exists");
                }
                boolean success = outputFile.renameTo(originalName);
                if (success) {
                    if (connection != null)
                        connection.disconnect();
                    onDownloadComplete();
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    stream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            isDownloading = false;
            prefs.edit().clear().commit();
            Log.d("Test", "Main");
            if (e.getMessage().equals("file exists"))
                onErrorDownload("Package Already Exists");
            else
                onErrorDownload("Internet Connection Problem Retry Download");
        }
    }

    private void onDownloadComplete() {
        Download download = new Download();
        download.setProgress(100);
        sendIntent(download);
        notificationManager.cancel(0);
        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(false);
        notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("File Downloaded");
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    private void onErrorDownload(String message) {
        Download download = new Download();
        download.setProgress(download.getProgress());
        sendIntent(download);
        notificationManager.cancel(0);
        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(false);
        notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    private void sendNotification(Download download) {
        sendIntent(download);
        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, download.getProgress(), false);
        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Downloading Progress " + download.getProgress() + "%" + " /100%");
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

    private void sendIntent(Download download) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ReadingListeningTestActivity.MESSAGE_PROGRESS);
        intent.putExtra("download", download);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(DownloadService.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private String packageName(String uri) {
        String[] parts = uri.split("/");
        return parts[parts.length - 1];
    }

    public File getCacheDir(String packageName) {
        File cache = null;
        File external = getApplication().getExternalCacheDir();
        if (external != null && external.exists()) {
            cache = external;
        } else {
            cache = getApplication().getCacheDir();
        }
        File file = new File(cache, packageName);
        return file;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no button clicklistenerr code in your post.

Comment: It is unclear to me if the service is started twice. Why is it downloading twice?

Comment: To prevent a double click which starts the service twice you can add in the onClick handler downloadPackage.setEnabled(false).

Comment: I am too confused. Why it download twice?

Comment: You should tell us! Is your code executed twice?

Comment: downloadPackage.setEnabled(false); 
I already added that line of code.Still problem

Comment: Then why didnt you tell us about it? Or added the code? You ate explaining nothing. How do you see that it downloads twice?

Comment: When i click download button, it downloaded the packages and after completion of that package it again start to download same packages. Its mine problem

Comment: Does it download packages? What are packages? You suggested that only one file should be downloaded.

Comment: packages means zip file that i have in server. 
eg. Set_7.zip

Comment: Packages: So you are downloading several files at once? Packages is plural of package. Confusing. And why not just talk abouf a file. Or files if there are more.

Comment: there are multiple zip file in server, 
eg. Package-A -> Set_1.zip
package-B -> Set_2.zip
downloadpackage listener is used for individual package which is used to download each individual zip file. No all file are downlaoded at once. Respective button should be clicked to download that respective zip file.
Mine problem is on while i click package-A button, it start download SEt_1.zip, after complete downloadibg  it again download the same zip file

Comment: Can be. Irrelevant. I have zip files here too. But where are you talking about? What are you doing? How many files shoud that service download?

Comment: Please read above comment.

Comment: `No all file are downlaoded at once. `??? You mean: one by one!?

Comment: In UI there are two button consists of Package-A and Package-B.
On which button user pressed, the zip file related to that package is to be download.I pressed on Package-A button,it dwonload the same file twice.Problem is pressing single package button it download twice same zip file. 
For Package-B, i must pressed that button, until i won't pressed it will not download.

Comment: `repository.send(packageSetsRequest);`. You have not explained what your code does. What should this code do? And what do you have if onSuccess is called then.

Comment: Please dont repeat yourself. You tell always the same. Better come wjrh new info. Explain how your code works. Or should do.

Comment: Found the problem. Problem is on realm. It cache the last SETID and Recent SetId. So twice request force to download the same file twice.. Thanks.
One question for you, how to selfstop service after download success or failure. Can you help me bro.